# What do the results of this AIDA64 System Stability test mean?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, temperature

[image]

[image]

I think it's very bad but what exactly does this test of my laptop performance indicate? Hardware problems?

Comment: Good on you for asking here! Because you need some reassurance. Your laptop is fine! Modern laptops and their CPUs are *purposefully engineered* to allow for high temperatures and, if maximum temperature is reached, throttling to keep temperature under control. The "overheating detected" warning you see is a bit misleading. In reality, if you laptop actually did overheat, the BIOS would have turned it off. So you're all good :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test is used to ensure system stability under *full* load.
The diagrams at the top tell you the temperature of your CPU and the individual cores as well as the HDD.

- On laptops these temperatures might jump due to throttling.

The second diagram shows CPU utilization in comparison to the full system capabilities.

- Once the utilization dips below 99%, you experience *thermal throttling* where the CPU is forcefully slowed down to prevent overheating but remain active (in the case of *real* overheating the PC/laptop would simply shutdown, ie. black screen and everything stops).
- You experience thermal-throttling but that's not bad as you are using a laptop and laptops are known for thermal-throttling due to space issues inside the case. There is simply no way to fit a large heat-sink and a fan inside a laptop's case.

The table at the bottom contains information about the maximum temperature, the minimum temperature and the average over the course of the time the test was done.
It also tells you more about the fan activity (RPM) and the power (Watts) your CPU received. The clock speed is monitored as well to help you analyzing the diagrams.

- Your temperatures are pretty normal for laptops, I rarely see them below 50 and the maximum of 105 is the usual throttling-temperature.
- The fan with >2500 RPM and up to 4500 RPM is just fine, it's small so it has to turn faster to move enough air.
- Power seems odd. I don't know the specs of your laptop but it seems to be more efficient at a low-medium utilization. Or it's turbo-boosting a lot and thus allows short bursts of 25W but averages at 10W.
- Clock speed is just according to CPU utilization. It clocks down to prevent overheating. The North Bridge remains at a stable speed because it does not have much to do and is unaffected by the CPU's heat output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you don't understand the diagrams and what they show things look scary.